# Does omnicppcomplete support typedef syntax

Tags: vim

I found that omnicppcomplete does not support typedef-ed struct name . I don't know it is a limitation of omnicppcomplet or it is because some missing configuration in my vim enviroment . Let me give you a dummy example to put it more clear.

```
typedef struct foo {
   int a;
   int b;
}foo_t ;

foo a ;
foo_t b ;
```

then after I hit "a." in insert mode ,  the following will appear in a popup window :

```
a m  + foo
b m  + foo
```

but after hit "b." ,  the following line appears at the bottom of the sreen :

```
"Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

======================edit after Habi's answer===============================

the ctags version I use is 5.4 and the latest is 5.8 . hint by Habi's example , I download the latest version of ctags and fix the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar example works here.

I use ctags this way:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
```

I use exuberant ctags version 5.7 and omnicppcomplete 0.41.

My settings of omnicppcomplete are:

```
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr=1
let OmniCpp_ShowScopeInAbbr=1
let OmniCpp_SelectFirstItem=2
```

Comment: @habi : the ctags version in the linux box I login is 5.4 , apparently  out of date . hint by your example , I try to use the latest version of ctags , it works now . thanks for your help .